# Honor play won't install apks and apps from unknown sources

Tags: side-loading

can't find any specific info on the honor play and why I cant install apks and unknown sources apps. The menus seem to be a little different to general android advice and I feel I've got the right options checked but I'm confused as heck. For info it's an honor play, android version 9, don't want to root the device, trying to install older update on Google play services pre March 2017 so I can spoof location but no apks seem to work. [image]

Whenever I try to install any 3rd party apps or apks I get this message or similar, I've checked the options and on honor play there's a list of programs such as browsers and apps where I can allow them to install programs and they all have permission. There isn't a general option that covers everything like on most other android mobiles.

Comment: Check whether your device's **internal storage** has enough space or not. Due to low space also, this error is shown.